# reading mbox files using python and batch

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, mbox

Hello I have the following two scripts where a `batch script` calls a python script that prints the last email in a mbox file.But an error pops up in command window

> name msg is not defined

How can I initialize an mbox variable to execute my script? Below the two scripts i wrote

```
import mailbox
import sys
for msg in mailbox.mbox(sys.argv[1]):
    pass

print(msg)
```

And here is my batch script

```
@echo off
python get_last_mail.py C:\\Users\\hmk\Desktop\\emails-enron.mbox
pause
```

I really need your help.Thank you

Comment: Your goal is just to print the last email? Or to print all emails?

Comment: the last email.

Comment: Well, `msg` exists only in the scope of the `for` loop, but `print(msg)` is not placed in the loop body...

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out. The error resides in the way to define the argument 
The new batch script is the following

```
@echo off
set var= "C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\emails-enron.mbox"
python "get_last_mail.py" %var% >last
pause
```